# RADIUS configurations on Server 2008 R2 - WiFi issue

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, wifi, radius, nps

I have configured WiFi authentication on FortiGate 100D through RADIUS on Windows server 2008 R2.
When I'm trying to connect to the wifi from a PC (Win 10), it works only when I check "Use my Windows user account" checkbox.
If I put domain\user and password manually it doesn't work, I get a message "can't connect to this network".
Why it works only when I check "Use my Windows user account" and doesn't work when I write user\password manually? What is the difference between the two, and how can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Does it work when you add your domain to the username?

Comment: I can't answer you in the comments because I don't have 50 reputation.
I don't know if it's the right way to answer here but have no choice. I have tried both of these options **domain\username + password** and **username + password** and it doesn't work.
But I don't understand what the difference between checking *Use my Windows user account* checkbox or writing it manually. When I check the checkbox it put domain\user and password automatically.
[wifi connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZHVu.png) If it will help, I configured Fortigate and NPS according to this guide:
https://cookbook.for

Answer (score 0):

Already handled the issue.
You can connect only with user\password if you use Unencrypted authentication (PAP, SPAP) method. If you use MS-CHAP2 method it'll only work when checking Use my Windows user account checkbox.